# More graceful way to check multiple lists using dictionaries?

Tags: ms-access, vba

This is at an early stage, so I don't have code to share - but I want to make sure that I'm using the right tools from the start. My project is a budget optimization script. Right now, I am planning on using dictionaries to store the budget names and loop through each of those, then compare the expense ID against lists of expenses that are eligible for those budgets. I'm not sure if I'm planning on using the right tool.

To give an example of how it ought to work, if I have a medical expense, I want to pay for it from my health savings account HSA. However, if I don't have enough in my HSA, I will pay for it using my general funds. The HSA will be defined as a higher priority funding than general.

Another expense, like a bottle of bourbon, would still be checked against the HSA because it will loop through each budget from highest priority to lowest, but the ID would not be in the eligible list for the HSA, so it could only be paid for using the general funds (or another specialized fund in between).

Complicating this, the number and names of budgets are not limited to a specific quantity. I want to be able to define 2 or 200 budgets as needs change. What is eligible will be defined in a query set up for each budget against the expense list. (So, something like

```
select expenseid from tblexpenses where category in ("MEDICAL","DENTAL")
```

would be for the HSA, but another might have overlap with another budget like one set up due to an old insurance pot of money. That eligibility query might be:

```
select expenseid from tblexpenses where category = "DENTAL" and expensedate < to_date("2018-01-01","yyyy-mm-dd");
```

There is a table where all budgets and their eligibility query names are stored. I'll use this to populate a list of budgets and use in the loop for testing expenses.

My current overall plan is to:

1. Create list of budgets (dictionary)
2. Create list(s) of eligibility (dictionary?) from multiple queries  that generate lists of eligible expenseids.
3. Assess expenses, rank them from most to least important
4. For each budget, compare each expense id (string) vs. eligibility
5. If the expense id is in the eligibility list for the budget and the budget is greater than the expense, mark as funded by that budget, reduce the budget used by that amount, and move on.
6. If not, then test the next budget (goto 5), until no more budgets. If no matches, then mark as unfunded.
7. Do this for each expense until end of file.
8. At the end, report out remaining budgets and how each expense was
   paid.

My question is what would do this most elegantly for storing building the multiple lists. I've been considering either directly querying the tables, using recordset, arrays, or the dictionaries and so far it looks like the dictionary is the winner, but I don't know how to replicate the query that I need for the test, which in SQL would be something like SELECT count(1) from tblEligibility WHERE budget = [BudgetID] and expenseID = [ExpenseID]. Dictionaries seem to be able to do the last check for the expense ID, but not both at the same time.

Suggestions? Am I on the right track?

EDIT - tl:dr; Version:

I need to work with three lists. One is static and an easy list that drives a loop. The second is an eligibility list with two data elements - budget id and expense id - that I need to be able to check if a combination pair exists in that list. The last are values that I will need to be able to modify as I go. All lists are populated by either tables or queries that will exist within the Access database.

Comment: Yes. Depending on your method of usage, it might be a good thing to plan on implementing a form to control the data you're looking for. But, its difficult to understand the exact nuances of what you need with this question.

Comment: Thanks for not ripping me to shreds. :) I know that it would be better to post code, but I don't want to get too far in and find out I'm using a screwdriver as a hammer. I updated the question with a tl:dr; version that hopefully is a bit more clear. Basically, I have three different types of lists that I need to track and I'm not sure what's the best thing to use on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested dictionaries might be ok, but I'd consider building a more maintainable custom object

[image: ObjectsVsNestedDictionaries]

---

.

**Edit**

A more specific scenario to illustrate data flow and object usage
(not having all details and requirements, this is how I would approach the project)

---

.

**Budgets** Worksheet - populated from Database / Query

[image: Budgets]

---

.

**Expenses** Table - populated from Database / Query

[image: Expenses]

---

.

**Module1** - Main Sub - **`pseudo-code`** (not working, just high level structure)

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SetBudgets()
    Dim wsB As Worksheet, wsE As Worksheet, budgets As clsBudget, itm As Range

    Set wsB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Budgets")
    Set wsE = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Expense")
    Set budgets = New clsBudget

    Dim ok As Boolean, funded As Boolean, budget As clsBudget

    ok = True
    For Each itm In wsB.UsedRange.Rows      'Initialize Budgets
        With itm
            If ok Then ok = budgets.Init(.Cells(1), .Cells(2), .Cells(3), .Cells(4))
        End With
    Next

    funded = True
    Set budget = New clsBudget
    If ok Then
        For Each itm In wsE.UsedRange.Rows  'Commit Expenses
            For Each budget In budgets
                funded = budget.Commit(itm.Cells(4), itm.Cells(5))
                If funded Then
                    itm.Cells(7) = "Funded by budget " & budget.BudgetFullName
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If Not funded Then itm.Cells(7) = "Unfunded"
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

To optimize for performance move all data (both sheets) to arrays

---

.

**Class Implementation - clsBudget** - **`pseudo-code`** (not working, just high level structure)

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Const ELIGIBILITY_LIST_DELIMITER = "||"

Private thisPriority    As Long     'Managed by the class
Private totalBudgets    As Long     'Managed by the class

Private priority        As Long     'Validated by the class
Private funds           As Double   '>= 0
Private fullName        As String   'Validated by the class (no special chars)
Private shortName       As String   'Validated by the class - extract initials
Private categories      As Dictionary   'No special chars, include other requirements...

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    SetGlobals True
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    SetGlobals False
End Sub

Private Sub SetGlobals(Optional ByVal Init = False) 'reset all private variables
    thisPriority = 0
    totalBudgets = 0
    fullName = vbNullString
    '...
End Sub

Public Property Get BudgetFullName()  'define all accessor methods, and read-only props
    BudgetFullName = fullName
End Property

Public Function Init(ByVal budgetLonglName As Byte, ByVal budgetPriority As Long, _
       ByVal availableFunds As Double, ByVal eligibilityList As String) As Boolean

    If Len(budgetLonglName) = 0 Then Exit Function          'Return Error Details
    If budgetPriority <= currentPriority Then Exit Function 'Return Error Details
    If availableFunds <= 0 Then Exit Function               'Return Error Details
    If Len(eligibilityList) = 0 Then Exit Function          'Return Error Details

    fullName = budgetLonglName  'Remove special chars ("!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?[]\;',./""")
    shortName = Split(fullName) 'For each itm extract first letter
    priority = budgetPriority
    funds = availableFunds

    Dim eList As Variant, cat As Variant
    eList = Split(eligibilityList, ELIGIBILITY_LIST_DELIMITER)

    For Each cat In eList
        'Remove special chars ("!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?[]\;',./""")
        If Len(cat) > 0 Then categories(cat) = 0
    Next

    If categories.Count > 0 Then    'Budget is OK
        thisPriority = priority
        totalBudgets = totalBudgets + 1
        Init = True
    Else
        'Return Error Details
    End If
End Function

Private Function IsAvailable(ByVal category As String, _
                             ByVal expense As Currency) As Boolean

    If categories.Exists(category) Then IsAvailable = expense <= funds

End Function

Public Function Commit(ByVal category As String, _
                       ByVal expense As Currency) As Boolean
    If IsAvailable(category, expense) Then
        funds = funds - expense
        Commit = True
    End If
End Function
```

---

More logic will be needed to define eligibility mapping for sub-categories (Other, etc), but the main relationship between Budgets and Expenses is driven by the Category field

Comment: very nice explanation. +1

Comment: Thank you very much for this. One question that I have is how would I reference these class objects when the budget names are not known ahead of time? In this case, I have HSA, General, and other but the actual list will be different and unknown to me. If I loop through the values in a table an create classes HSA, GF, and O, then I can use the functions HSA.IsAvailable with hard coded, but how do I indirectly call them? A CallbyName function?

Comment: I added details to show how Budgets and Expenses are dynamic (other adjustments can be made based on your requirements)